# android - how to have a clickable AND checkable textview

Tags: android, button, textview, statelist

I want to have the following:
a textview that
.)changes its background when clicked
.)maintains that background until it is clicked again

it all comes down to the "checkable" state, but i couldnt figure out how this exactly works. here is the xml i am using for background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menuselected"
android:state_pressed="true" />

<!-- checked -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menuselected"
android:state_checked="true" />

<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transpixel"/>

</selector>
```

Update: it partly works now. I adopted most of the code from http://kmansoft.com/2011/01/11/checkable-image-button/ for my custom Textview. I did this as actually, I need the functionality of a radio button as well.
Now I can check a Textview, but I cant uncheck it. Does anybody see why that could be the case?

Answer (score 8):

You can  use CheckedTextView with
checkMark null
and
background your selectable

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable"/>
```

your selectable can be

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selector" />
</selector>
```

Comment: OMG I have been developing for 5 years and only now I learned about the CheckedTextView ))

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom `TextView` implementing [`android.widget.Checkable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) interface. That should be sufficient to make your selector work.

Below is the example implementation:

```
public class CheckableTextView extends TextView implements Checkable {
    private boolean isOn=false;

    public CheckableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CheckableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked())
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isOn=checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isOn;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        isOn=!isOn;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so far, that seems reasonable. i am unsure how to implement the methods isChecked(), setChecked(boolean a) and toggle() though. could you give me an hints on that?

Comment: that is pretty straightforward, but somehow it still doesnt work. this question is still open.

Comment: @user1995099 to you call `toggle()` on click? Also, a call to refreshDrawableState() might be needed when you change the state.

Comment: i added the call to refreshDrawableState() to toggle() as well as to setCkecked(a), it doesnt change anything. i dont know if i call toggle on click, do i have to override a method for that?

Comment: @user1995099 also, try overriding onCreateDrawableState() method as shown in the example.

Comment: hm it seems you copied that from http://kmansoft.com/2011/01/11/checkable-image-button/ , but there they declare styleables through xm, so i think its a bit more complicated than this.

Comment: @user1995099 they declare styleables for other purposes (being able to set the initial checked state and some custom parameter from xml). This is not absolutely necessary in your case.

Comment: it still does not work. Although, i erased the "if" part of onCreateDrawableState(), since it has a reference to CHECKED_STATE_SET, which, in the example in my previous comment, has a reference to some styleable.